# How to declare a variable that accepts method reference of any type Function<>

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I am trying to declare a variable that accepts method reference of any type ***Function<AnyObject, AnyObject or Any Enum>***

This method reference would be used in mapper where I accept some inputs and map the respective value by calling the method referred to another object.

```
@Data // Lombok
public class ReferenceSample<T, R> {

  private final Function<T, R > methodReference; // should be able to accept any method reference

}
```

Following are the possible methods

```
     public class Common {

          public static String getMethod1(String a) {
            // Process
            return "result1";
          }

          public static SomeEnum getMethod2(String b) {
            // Process
            return SomeEnum.DATA;
          }
        }
```

When I try to create the object

```
new ReferenceSample(Common::getMethod1);
```

I get the following error

```
java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
    incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

Comment: check out java.lang.reflect

Comment: @ControlAltDel Can you elaborate on what you are refering to?

Comment: How would that be useful? How would you call the function?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

Comment: @ControlAltDel I am not sure what I am supposed to do here with reflection.

Comment: @Sweeper methodReference.apply("SomeString"). if that's what you meant.

Comment: But `getMethod1` doesn't take a string?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, it does take the string.

Comment: On a level as abstract as this question currently stands, the only answer is "No, that's not possible". However, this seems to be an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/377791). Can you describe more specifically, what it is you are trying to do? If some corporate limitation exists, try to construct equivalent but obfuscated code.

Comment: @Izruo I would be using this methodReference in a dynamic mapper where i would call the method reference and get the value. currently, there is no code for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needs to specialize the generic types as shown below.

```
public class Reference
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Reference app = new Reference ();
        app.test ();
    }

    private void test ()
    {
        int[] row = {1, 1, 5, 2, 4};

        System.out.println ("Input: " + Arrays.toString (row));

        // This fails because the generic types have not been specified
        ReferenceSample rs1 = new ReferenceSample (Common::getMethod1);
        
        // This compiles but isn't specialized
        ReferenceSample<?, ?> rs2 = new ReferenceSample<> (Common::getMethod1);
        
        // This is preferred because it specifies the types precisely
        ReferenceSample<String, String> rs3 = new ReferenceSample<> (Common::getMethod1);
    }
}

class ReferenceSample<T, R>
{
    public Function<T, R> methodReference; // should be able to accept any method reference

    public ReferenceSample (Function<T, R> methodReference)
    {
        this.methodReference = methodReference;
    }
}

class Common
{
    public static String getMethod1 (String a)
    {
        // Process
        return "result1";
    }

    public static String getMethod2 (String b)
    {
        // Process
        return "+" + b + "+";
    }
}
```